# Aptana Studio 3 PHP code completion for mixed types?

Tags: php, ide, aptana, code-completion

I am currently working in Aptana Studio 3 (which appears to be 3.0.7 at this time) using PHP. I have a function that will return an instance of another object, but that object is determined at run-time. Therefore, it is not possible to decorate the function with relevant comments. Instead, I am looking for a clean solution to decorare the caller with tags for code complete. How can I do this?

```
/**
 * Represents a person.
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * Contains the identifier.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $PersonId;

    /**
     * Contains the string.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $Name;
}

/**
 * A simple factor example.
 * 
 * @return mixed
 */
function CreateExample( $zClass )
{
    return new $zClass();
}

/* @var $x Person */
$x = CreateExample( 'Person' ) instanceof Person;
```

After decoration with both a comment and instanceof, it finally worked, but this looks horrible! Is there no better way to use *one* solution and make it work as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. First, I believe that `CreateExample( 'Person' ) instanceof Person` simply assign a primitive boolean into `$x`. That is also the reason you will not get code-assist on `$x`, even if you edit the return of `CreateExample` to `@return Person`.

Setting `$x = CreatePerson( 'Person' );` will get you the CA in case you have the `CreateExample` doc set-up correctly.

Now, since you have a mixed returned type, one solution is to use the `@var` doc, as you did. However, there is another solution that you can use.

I assume you know all the possible return types, so in that case you can *pipe* those types in the `CreateExample` @return:

`@return Person|OtherClass|ThirdClass`

Now, when you code-assist `$x` you will get an aggregation of all the available elements from *all* the classes you piped.

Hope that helps!